# Freezing the width of an HTML table column

Tags: html, css, fixed

I'm trying to make a table with a fixed column, and i'm following this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/

Container:

```
 div { 
            width: 600px; 
            overflow-x:scroll;  
            margin-left:5em; 
            overflow-y:visible;
            padding-bottom:1px;
        }
```

Fixed column:

```
.headcol {
            position:absolute; 
            width:5em; 
            left:0;
            top:auto;
            border-right: 0px none black; 
            border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
            margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
        }
```

The problem is that if the container has a fixed height, say 100px, the fixed column keeps it's default height without getting attached to the scrollbar.

Comment: I don't understand the question... What do you mean by *default height* and what do you mean by *attached to scrollbar*?

Comment: I think he means this is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/YMvk9/783/

Comment: Oh ok. So the question is actually: **I want to have first column fixed but the whole table should be vertically scrollable as well**? And don't then come with a new condition that you also want fixed first row. ;) That would actually make it extremely interesting. I already find the example in JSFiddle a very nice trick. Extremely clever...

Comment: I've edited my answer an added a different approach

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an extra container, which you can set to relative positioning.

```
div#container{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

You can see in the example below that the fixed rows scrolls vertically with the rest of the rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/VRNsX/

If you aren't averse to a little jQuery, here is another approach I worked out:

```
$('#tbl').scroll(function(e) {
    var self = this;
    $('.headcol').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            'top': ($(this).index('.headcol') * $(this).outerHeight() + 3) - $(self).scrollTop()
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YMvk9/786/

Comment: @Asad, I works fine when u scroll, but how can i hide the fixed column in the beginning, like not show all the 9 rows?